# taking values using post method from a cloned field

Tags: php, mysql, clone

```
<table class="manual_journal_table table table-bordered">
    <tr> 
       <th>Account</th>
       <th>Party</th>
       <th>Debit</th>
       <th>Credit</th>
       <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="clone">
        <td><input type="text" required name="account" id="account"></td>
        <td><input type="text" required name="party" id="party"></td>
        <td><input type="text" required name="debit" id="debit"></td>
        <td><input type="text" required name="credit" id="credit"></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="removejournal btn btn-flat btn-danger">Remove</a></td> 
    </tr> 
</table> 
<a href="#" class="add_new_row btn btn-flat btn-success">Add New Row</a>
```

I want to take values from the cloned table using post method and then I want to insert it into the database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is chance of adding more rows which literally means more values. Since your adding only name without an array value the values will be overwritten and you wont get all the values.

Eg : instead `name="account"` to `name="account[]"`

If I were you then I would have taken a better approach to this by using the array in well formatted so that the data would be posted to the action appropriately like following

Observer **name** field carefully, even I have replaced **id** with **class**

> Note : I higly suggest you not to create table for every new row added
>   instead append that to the current table as follows

```
<tr class="clone">
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[1][account]" class="account"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[1][party]" class="party"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[1][debit]" class="debit"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[1][credit]" class="credit"></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removejournal btn btn-flat btn-danger">Remove</a></td> 
</tr>

<tr class="clone">
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[2][account]" class="account"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[2][party]" class="party"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[2][debit]" class="debit"></td>
    <td><input type="text" required name="payment_details[2][credit]" class="credit"></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removejournal btn btn-flat btn-danger">Remove</a></td> 
</tr>
```

Now in your controller action or respective page you will get the data in the following format

```
payment_details =>
    [1] =>
        [account] => 'xyz'
        [party] =>  'xyz'
        [debit] =>  'xyz'
        [credit] => 'xyz'
    [2] =>
        [account] => 'xyz'
        [party] =>  'xyz'
        [debit] =>  'xyz'
        [credit] => 'xyz'
```

Which you can manage easily by looping into the **payment_details**